# Capture bunyan logs / Peek into bunyan logger

Tags: node.js, logging, bunyan

I have a function, which uses bunyan logger passed to it for logging.

The global logger is used across the whole application to provide logging facilities for many components. This way we have a centralized log. Most of the time we just pass this global logger to all functions, which need it.

However, in some cases when I call the aforementioned function I want to be able to access the logs written by this exact function call, but at the same time I want to maintain standard logging behavior (i.e. writing logs to the centralized log), so I can't just pass a new logger instance to it.

What is the best way to solve this with bunyan?

The code should look somewhat like this:

```js
const funcCallLogger = globalLogger.cloneSomehow();

doSomeWork(funcCallLogger).then(() => {
  const logs = funcCallLogger.getWritenLogs();
  // logs should be an array of all logs written to funcCallLogger
  // at the same time all logs written to funcCallLogger must also be
  // reflected in globalLogger
});

function doSomeWork (logger) {
  logger.info('Doing some work...');
  await ...
}
```

I was thinking about creating a child logger and assigning a custom stream to it for log collecting, but I'm not sure if this is the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to create a child logger and to configure it to use the custom writable stream in order to collect and process all log entries written to it. This way all logs from child logger are flowing to the global logger (so this doesn't break the normal logging behavior) and at the same time I have ability to collect the logs streamed to this custom instance.

Here's the sample code:

```ts
import * as stream from 'stream';


export class LogAccumulatingStream extends stream.Writable {

  private logs: string[] = [];


  public _write (chunk: any, encoding: string, callback: Function): void {
    this.logs.push(chunk.toString());
    callback();
  }

  public getLogs (): string[] {
    return this.logs;
  }

}
```

And here's how I run it:

```ts
const childLogger = globalLogger.child({
  component: 'SomeWorker'
});

const logsAccumulator = new LogAccumulatingStream();

const stream = new PrettyStream({ useColor: false });

stream.pipe(logsAccumulator);

childLogger.addStream({
  level: 'debug',
  type: 'raw',
  stream
});

await someWorker.run(childLogger);

const workerLogs = logsAccumulator.getLogs();
```

I'm using PrettyStream to format the logs as strings and then I pipe it to my LogAccumulatingStream, but you can use the LogAccumulatingStream directly if desired, just rewrite it to handle objects instead of strings.

I'm not sure if this is the best possible solution, so comments and further answers are very welcome.